# Aligning and italicising table column headings using Rmarkdown and pander

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pander

I am writing a rmarkdown document knitting to pdf with tables taken from portions of lists from the ezANOVA package. The tables are made using the pander package. Toy Rmarkdown file with toy dataset below.

````
---
title: "Table Doc"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
#set global knit options  parameters. 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8, fig.path='Figs/', 
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, dev = 'pdf')
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# toy data
id <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), 5)
group1 <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), 10))
group2 <- factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10))
dv <- runif(20, min = 0, max = 10)
df <- data.frame(id, group1, group2, dv)
```

``` {r anova, echo = FALSE}
library(ez)
library(plyr)
library(pander)

# create anova object
anOb <- ezANOVA(df,
                dv = dv,
                wid = id,
                between = c(group1, group2),
                type = 3,
                detailed = TRUE)

# extract the output table from the anova object, reduce it down to only desired columns
anOb <- data.frame(anOb[[1]][, c("Effect", "F", "p", "p<.05")])

# format entries in columns
anOb[,2] <- format( round (anOb[,2], digits = 1), nsmall = 1)
anOb[,3] <- format( round (anOb[,3], digits = 4), nsmall = 1)

pander(anOb, justify = c("left", "center", "center", "right"))
```
````

Now I have a few problems

a) For the last three columns I would like to have the column heading in the table aligned in the center, but the actual column entries underneath those headings aligned to the right.

b) I would like to have the column headings 'F' and 'p' in italics and the 'p' in the 'p<.05' column in italics also but the rest in normal font. So they read *F*, *p* and *p*<.05

I tried renaming the column headings using plyr::rename like so

```
anOb <- rename(anOb, c("F" = "italic(F)", "p" = "italic(p)", "p<.05" = ""))
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In markdown, you have to use the markdown syntax for italics, which is wrapping text between a star or underscore:

```
> names(anOb) <- c('Effect', '*F*', '*p*', '*p<.05*')
> pander(anOb)

-----------------------------------------
    Effect       *F*     *p*     *p<.05* 
--------------- ------ -------- ---------
  (Intercept)    52.3   0.0019      *    

    group1       1.3    0.3180           

    group2       2.0    0.2261           

 group1:group2   3.7    0.1273           
-----------------------------------------
```

If you want to do that in a programmatic way, you can also use the `pandoc.emphasis` helper function to add the starts to a string.

But your other problem is due to a bug in the package, for which I've just proposed a fix on [GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/pull/254). Please feel free to give a try to that branch and report back on GH -- I will try to get some time later this week to clean up the related unit tests and merge the branch if everything seem to be OK.

Comment: thank you @daroczig i should have thought of markdown formatting for italics. i am still getting used to switching between .R and .rmd. As for the fix, I am afraid I am still a relative novice to GH; not much beyond clone/status/add/commit/push/pull. Thus adapting your code (adding 2 blank spaces to the left of numbers that don't fill cells, is that right?) to my toy problem above is a little beyond me (e.g. I am not sure what the lines that start with '@@' are supposed to do). Sorry for my ignorance. I will try again a little later.

Comment: @llewmills you can give that branch a try by installing that development version of `pander` via eg `devtools::install_github('rapporter/pander@simple-and-multiline-aligment-fix')`, and then you can simply use `pander` as before (after restarting your session or reloading the package).

Comment: I copied the code you pasted into your last comment and it loaded fine. Restarted R and then unloaded the and reloaded the package but the 3-digit values (e.g. 2.3) are still centered rather than flush to the right of the column.

Comment: @llewmills ah, I just understood what you try to achieve: having a different alignment for the row headers and actual values. Well, that's not possible based on [pandoc's table standards](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables).

Comment: Ah, I see. So there is no way in pander to assign alignment to individual cells? Might have to go back to word for tables, save them as .png then add them to rmarkdown. Not ideal but standards of formatting require it I think.

Comment: @llewmills in markdown, you can align columns but not individual cells.

Comment: is there any way to put spaces after the column headings, so that you achieve a sort of de facto column centering? I tried just using \\ and \qquad but they didn't work. Neither did just adding the spaces.

Comment: @llewmills added a comment on your follow-up question with a suggestion on a workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253549/inserting-blank-spaces-at-the-end-of-a-column-name-in-a-table-using-pander#comment60136878_36253549 -- but in short, it's not possible in any convenient way.