# Inserting blank spaces at the end of a column name in a table using pander

Tags: knitr, r-markdown, pander

I am trying to find a way of centering a column heading in a pander table using knitr to pdf in rmarkdwon, but keeping the column entries *right* justified.

````
---
title: "Table Doc"
output: pdf_document
---



```{r table, echo = FALSE}

table1 <- anova(lm(Petal.Length ~ Species*Petal.Width, iris))

names(table1) <- c("DF", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "*F*", "*p*")

library(pander)

pander(table1, justify = c("left", rep("right", 5)))

```
````

There is no way to align individual cells inside a table in pandoc apparently. I want the entries to be to the right so they are all aligned properly but sit the column headings '*F*' and '*p*' in the center. So what I need to do is insert blank spaces after *F* and *p* to force them into the center. How do I do this? I tried simply inserting the blank spaces:

```
names(table1) <- c("DF", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "*F*    ", "*p*    ")
```

but the spaces are not recognised by pander.

I also tried LaTex spacing characters

```
names(table1) <- c("DF", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "*F*\\", "*p*\\")
```

but this didn't work either. Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: `pander` removes trailing or leading white-space from cells on purpose -- so that it can add that based on what cell alignment was set for the given column. The only workaround to stop this behaviour is to use a eg non-breaking or some Unice space instead of the ASCII 32.

Comment: thank you @daroczig. I added the Unicode and that seems to be working. So 'names(table1) <- c("DF", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F\u00A0\u00A0", "p")' seems to achieve the desired result. It's not super pretty or efficient but it works. Thank you for your help again. After our last exchange I looked into using LaTex for tables but then you have to just write the whole table out, which sort of defeats the purpose of adaptive documents. Thank you for pander!